# PHP: Assign multiple variables in if statement

Tags: php, if-statement, variable-assignment

I don't seem to be able to assign multiple variables in an `"if"` statement. The following code:

```
<?php

function a ($var)
{
    if ($var == 1)
    {
        return 'foo';
    }

    return false;
}

function b ($var)
{
    if ($var == 1)
    {
        return 'bar';
    }

    return false;
}

if ($result1 = a(1) && $result2 = b(1))
{
    echo $result1 . ' ' . $result2;
}

?>
```

Returns "1 bar" rather than "foo bar". If I remove the second condition/assignment it returns "foo".

Is there a way to assign multiple variables in an "if" statement or are we limited to just one?

Comment: This is a very bad idea.  What if you put an 'or' condition between two assignments?  IF (e=mc^2 or E=Mc^2) ...  Did the second assignment execute?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is all about operator precedence

```
<?php

function a ($var)
{
    if ($var == 1)
    {
        return 'foo';
    }

    return false;
}

function b ($var)
{
    if ($var == 1)
    {
        return 'bar';
    }

    return false;
}

if (($result1 = a(1)) && ($result2 = b(1)))
{
    echo $result1 . ' ' . $result2;
}

?>
```

https://repl.it/IQcU

**UPDATE**

assignment operator `=` is right-asscoiative, that means, evaluation of operand on rhs has precedence over the lhs operand.

thus,

```
$result1 = a(1) && $result2 = b(1)
```

is equivalent of,

```
$result1 = (a(1) && $result2 = b(1))
```

which evaluates

```
$result1 = ("foo" && [other valild assignment] )
```

which will result that,

`$result1` becomes `true`

and `echo true`/string value of boolean true (`strval(true)`) outputs/is 1

you can also check that revision, https://repl.it/IQcU/1

to see that below statement

```
$result1 = a(1) && $result2 = b(1)
```

is equivalent of this one.

```
 $result1 = (a(1) && $result2 = b(1))
```

Comment: correct.+1.But need to add more explanation regarding why `1 bar` is coming?

Comment: Aha. Can't believe I never came across this before. Normally I'm either assigning just a single value in the if condition or doing multiple comparisons ($a == 'foo'), which apparently do not associate across && and similar structures. I thought && was sort of a condition separator but apparently when doing assignment it is not. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Need to add parentheses`()` in each assignment like below:-

```
if (($result1 = a(1)) && ($result2 = b(1)))
{
    echo $result1 . ' ' . $result2;
}
```

Output:- https://eval.in/804770

Correct explanation is given by ***@marmeladze*** here:-

[Why `1 bar` is coming through OP's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44172350/4248328)

Answer (score 1):

The last if statements need some brackets, it should have been:

```
if (($result1 = a(1)) && ($result2 = b(1)))
{
     echo $result1 . ' ' . $result2;
}
```

This ensures that things in the bracket are executed first and it will help.

Comment: correct.+1.But need to add more explanation regarding why `1 bar` is coming?

Comment: Things in the bracket are executed first. Without them it would have been: if ($result1 = a(1) && $result2 = b(1)) resulting in non assignment of the second variable.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `==` to check a condition.

Try this,

```
if ($result1 == a(1) && $result2 == b(1))
{
    echo $result1 . ' ' . $result2;
}
```

Checked with belo example

```
<?php 

function a ($var)
{
    if ($var == 1)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    return false;
}

function b ($var)
{
    if ($var == 1)
    {
        return 2;
    }

    return false;
}

if (1 == a(1) && 2 == b(1))
{
    echo 'success';
}
?>
```

Comment: I don't think it's anyhow solving problem of OP or giving him a clue why `1 bar` is coming in his case?